# how to make result in multiple choice quiz game [java]

Tags: java

Today I have created Multiple Choice Quiz Games from *Netbeans*. 
I have created it containing more than 5 Question and which has 4 choices each. (Every question has own class) 
I want to make result/score of the Quiz. But I don't know how to do?

Here my Quiz' Screenshot:

[image: here]

PS: 120 are 1200.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have the right answer to the given ones (on your screen shot the question is 30*40, but the correct answer(=1200) is not there)

Since you have the questions as objects, create an attribute that would hold the correct answer.

Comment: what do you mean you typed 1200 before. the value there is 1200 but the button is too small to fit? then change the font or the button size

Comment: the answer are 1200 but there only 120